# kubernetes eviction does not follow rolling update strategy

Tags: kubernetes

context:

- deployment/service/pod with one replica (because it uses an expensive shared resource, would be a big rewrite to change this)
- rolling update strategy: maxsurge 1, maxunavailable 0 (because short-term sharing of the expensive resource is acceptable)
- unwanted downtime of the service when the pod is evicted because of predictable reasons

I know the rolling update strategy is followed perfectly when I run `kubectl rollout restart ...`, but when a pod is killed due to predictable reasons (in our setup, typically the autoscaler downscaling the cluster), this doesn't happen.

Is there a functionality in k8s that I'm missing that can emulate the behaviour of a rolling update strategy?

The closest I'm getting is

- poddisruptionbudget forcing at least one to be online
- rollout restart every X minutes

but I can't help feeling there should be some form of trigger or interaction that can be used to cleanly solve this.

for clarity:
wanted timeline:

- cluster autoscaler notifies (eviction api) that the pod needs to go
- a new pod is created (double resource usage start)
- the new pod is ready
- the old pod is killed (double resource usage end)
  no downtime, slight period of double resource usage

actual timeline:

- eviction api
- old pod is killed (downtime start)
- new pod is created
- new pod is ready (downtime end)

Comment: Can you increase your pod's resource requests so it doesn't get evicted?  I don't think there's a way to cause the eviction process to allocate still more resources somewhere, and wait indefinitely for something else to come up, before the pod is killed and the node's resource usage is within acceptable bounds again.

Comment: No, the pods aren't using a lot of resources at all, it gets evicted because of the autoscaler scaling down the cluster at night. And (on AKS at least) this leads to the most recent nodes getting drained, which leads to the specific pod with this issue experiencing downtime.

Comment: [PodDisruptionBudget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) on its own should address that; the cluster autoscaler scaling in the cluster should be a "voluntary disruption" that takes PDB into account.

Comment: Yes, but I can't tell it to start a new pod *before* killing the old one that way, can I? I can only block the autoscale, which is an issue in itself. (edit: edited the question to clarify the timelines a bit)

Comment: The other question I'd ask on the timeline is whether your pod has appropriate readiness probes set.  If it doesn't then it's possible that the new pod is created and immediately considered "ready", but you get some downtime before it's fully functional.

Comment: The readiness probes are less than ideal, but function well enough (no downtime is experienced when we run `kubectl rollout restart ...` for example)